# How to build app locker application in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, pubspec

I want to create an app which allows lock on the other apps in device. It like parenting control app. If parents lock some app in the device. It would not be accessed by the child or deleted by him. For any interaction with app it would ask for the pin. Is it possible to build such application in flutter. If so what are the plugins are implementation. I just need an idea.

Comment: you have to use method channels to achieve this type of app, you can trigger the app open and close event using USAGE_STATS and about block uninstallation of the app here is a link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14098214/how-to-programmatically-prevent-install-uninstall-of-applications-in-android