# Start AlarmManager if device is rebooted

Tags: android, restart, android-alarms, reboot

In my app I want to run some code every day at a specific time using an `AlarmManager`. In the [android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) I found this:

> Registered alarms are retained while the device is asleep [...] but will be cleared if it is turned off and rebooted.

And that is the problem. I want to run the code even if the user reboots the phone. If the user reboots the phone he currently has to relaunch my app to start alarms again. How can I prevent this? Is there a better mechanism I should use instead?

Comment: create a reciver for boot complete and set the alarm manager (clear if any previous alarms are there for your app too)

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315494/android-how-to-start-activity-on-boot-up/17315856#17315856

Comment: Very useful question.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Create Boot Receiver using following code :

```
public class BootBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context pContext, Intent intent) {
        if(intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED)){
            // Do your work related to alarm manager
        }
    }
}
```

In your Manifest, register this Broadcast receiver :

```
<receiver
android:name="com.yourapp.BootBroadcastReceiver"
android:enabled="true" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And don't forget to add permission in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: The onReceive() method does not appear to call getAction to ensure that the received Intent's action string matches the expected value, potentially making it possible for another actor to send a spoofed intent with no action string or a different action string and cause undesired behavior. So you should add this line of code in your onReceive():

if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
// do your work here
}

Comment: Do both receivers need to be defined in the `AndroidManifest`?

Answer (score 6):

Use can u create service using broadcast reciever on device boot up

```
 <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".YourReceiver"
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Permission:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to add a boot receiver in your manifest like this

```
<application ...  >

    <receiver android:name=".OnBootReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

And then create the boot receiver class like this...

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class OnBootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctxt, Intent intent) {
AlarmHelper.setAlarm(ctxt);
}
}
```

My alarm helper class is a simple start of day alarm like this...

```
public class AlarmHelper {

public static void testAlarm(Context context) {
Calendar when = Calendar.getInstance();
when.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
setAlarm(context, when);    
}

public static void setAlarm(Context context) {
Calendar when = Calendar.getInstance();
when.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);
when.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
when.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
when.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
setAlarm(context, when);
}

    @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private static void setAlarm(Context context, Calendar when) {

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context.getApplicationContext());

Boolean showNotifications = prefs.getBoolean("PREF_SHOW_NOTIFICATIONS",
false);

if (showNotifications) {    
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, getPendingIntent(context.getApplicationContext()));

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

Log.i(TAG, "Alarm set " + sdf.format(when.getTime()));
}
}
```

Comment: Make sure you put the uses permission (<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />)  into correct place in the manifest file. ( usually before activity)