# Restoring Alarms set with AlarmManager after device reboot

Tags: android

I want to create an Alarm for Android.

I've used so far an AlarmManager that sets on the given time and day.
And onReceive(), I have a NotificationManager that warns for a specific event.

My problem is that if the event is set for a week or month later, I may restart my device and my alarm will be lost.

Can someone explain me how can I save this alarm and restore it after reboot?

Comment: refer accepted answer of this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673746/start-alarmmanager-if-device-is-rebooted)

Answer (score 3):

you need to use a broadcast receiver that listens for the broadcast

```
android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

then restart your alarms from your broadcast receiver

Comment: @CommonsWare the sample project you mention has a dead link.  Please advise.

Comment: @AJW: Sorry! I got rid of that sample project from the book, as it uses the now-deprecated `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`. Here is a link to that project from an older edition of my book: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.8/AlarmManager/WakeCast

Comment: @CommonsWare  No apology necessary!  You go above and beyond to help others on SO.  I appreciate the link to the older edition.  Cheers!