# Alarm Manager after shutdown

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms

When I tried this code, everything is working fine except, service is not getting start after device reboot. I want to start same service automatically. I am testing this example by connecting mobile with USB. what do I need to change ?
[http://javatechig.com/android/repeat-alarm-example-in-android]

Comment: Try this. [Start AlarmManager if device is rebooted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673746/start-alarmmanager-if-device-is-rebooted)

Comment: Do you enabled this broadcast receiver "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"

Comment: <receiver android:name=".DeviceBootReceiver"
            android:enabled="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: You will find a full example of Alarms surviving reboots in the official docs.

Comment: google `android scheduling repeating alarms`

Answer (score 1):

try like this

```
   <!-- for reboot event to reset alarms -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

then

```
 <receiver
        android:name="com.yourapp.receiver.RestartAppReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

next you have to create the BroadcastReceiver class

```
public class RestartAppReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = "RestartAppReceiver";

    public RestartAppReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent != null) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            switch (action) {
                case Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED:
                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Start resetting alarms after reboot");


                    //restart what you need 


                    Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Finish resetting alarms after reboot");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i call RestartAppReceiver

Comment: @UsmanAsif  No need to make a call.define the manifest like this,then it will works when the reboot event happens

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a broadcast receiver that will listen for boot complete event and when that event is received start your service again

```
<receiver android:name=".Autostart">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

create a class like this and add your code in onReceive method

```
public class Autostart extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) 
    {
        Log.i("Autostart", "**********started************");
    }
}
```