# Enabling button for a limited time in android app

Tags: android

Here's an example, I want to be able to enable a button in my app, for a limited time (let's say 30 minutes), after a user action. After 30 minutes, this button will get disabled again.
What would be the best way to achieve this in android?

Because the user may restart device or close the app, I can't simply use a countdowntimer. Even so, given that there is a specific time interval start-end date, I can simply check against the current time and see what the state of the button should be. However, the user could simply put the phone's date back with 15 minutes so the button would continue to be enabled.

Comment: Have you tried alarmmanager?

Comment: you can store time of last time process done and than compare it to current time(DATETIME).

Comment: @AmitVaghela can we use MVP for that?

Comment: actually no need to use MVP, save these datetime data to sharedpreference.@AdityaVyas-Lakhan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Normal case**

- Button gets visible

  1. save timestamp and timezone info in shared preferences
  2. start `AlarmManager`, which will wake up and clear shared preferences and disable button state.

**Case, when user closes and opens the app**

- Button gets visible

  3. All previous steps plus each time app is being open check the difference between the value in shared preference (if there is one) and current time, depending on that show the button.

**Case when user changes time**

- Button gets visible

  4. All previous steps plus register for time change events in the `AndroidManifest` ([see how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6230951/1083957)) and perform necessary action to the `SharedPreferences`, depending how much the time has been changed.

Obviously, if user clears app's data this technique is useless, you have to perform syncing with backend ([Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) maybe??).

Answer (score 2):

You can use Handler's postDelayed method. See below-

```
    //when use press button
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                //disable your button here
            }
        }, 3*1000); //your delay time
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a countdowntimer every minute and then save that progress in a config file, for example. When the user has 30 minutes you can disable the button.
You can write a config file into the app inner folder where the user can't touch.
If the user closes the app over 7 minutes, in your config file exists these 7 minutes. And if the user put the phon's date back doesn't care ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here the best thing for you to do is to use a CountDown timer that writes the progress of your button enable time in the **PreferenceHelper**. 
Define a interval say maybe 30 sec or 1 min and fire this countdown timer as soon as your user action finishes.

After every 30 sec or after every 1 min depending upon your choice of interval update the value in preference helper.

Example with 1 min update interval

```
public void updateButtonDisableTimer(){
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

int oldTimerValue =  sharedpreferences.getInt("key", 0); // is the default value in case no value is found.
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
if(oldTimerValue > 30){
    //this the case when you need to stop the timer
     editor.putInt("key", 0);
   //Write code to disable the button
}else{
  int newValue = oldTimerValue + 1; //1 min is interval
  editor.putInt("key", newValue);
} 
editor.commit();
}
```

This will work in case of app close and all the other scenario. It may fail only when you clear the data. Hope it works :)

Answer (score 1):

> given that there is a specific time interval start-end date, I can
>   simply check against the current time and see what the state of the
>   button should be. However, the user could simply put the phone's date
>   back with 15 minutes so the button would continue to be enabled.

To avoid this, set an [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

> Because the user may restart device or close the app

Closing an app doesn't has any impact on AlarmManager once it sets. Restart, however, does. There are [ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673746/start-alarmmanager-if-device-is-rebooted) of recreating AlarmManager too. In short, you've to create the AlarmManager again. But it doesn't has any clue on what time it was set before. One way to achieve this is, store the time in shared preference alongside of setting the AlarmManager. Now you can fire the AlarmManager as many times as you want since you know the targeted time.

Once the AlarmManager triggers, simply enable/disable the button in question from the Activity/Service that Pending Intent provided.

Answer (score 0):

Save in Preferences start time using `System.currentTimeMillis()` and every time check if current time (same `System.currentTimeMillis()`) has past 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to disable the button for 30 minutes. 
btn.setEnabled(false);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

```
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1800000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            LoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    btn.setEnabled(true);

                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

OnClick of Button store current time in sharedPreference.
When you came back check difference between current time and sharedPref time. 
If its greater than 30 minutes then enable else it was disable.
For the first sharedPreference values is null at that time enable button

Answer (score 0):

I would apprach ths problem in the following way:

1. When Enabling the button, store the current time in the back end ( along with some indentifier for the device)
2. Next time this activity is displayed, Read from the DB
3. Comapare the time stored and current time.
4. Simple condition to establish if the button should be enabled or not.