# How to set an AlarmManager to run every first day of the month?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to have an android alarm manager to runs a service at the first day of every month. I have the folowing code:

```
     PersianCalendar persianCalendar = new PersianCalendar();
    persianCalendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
   if( persianCalendar.getPersianDay()==1){

    Intent intent = new Intent(UsersActivity.this, AppsNetUsageReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
           alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, persianCalendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
}
```

How can I guarantee my service runs successfully if the device was off or other reason prevent to my service do its work?

Answer (score 0):

**You have to set the next alarm when previous alarm is received.**

There is `setRepeating(@AlarmType int type, long triggerAtMillis,long intervalMillis, PendingIntent operation)` method in AlarmManager which can be used to set repeating alarms like every hour or every 15 min.

But in this case you can't provide `intervalMillis` since intervals can vary due to different no of days in months.

And as @Ya Si said, there are other ways to set alarms apart from AlarmManager which handles power-off/restarting cases automatically.
If you still want to use AlarmManager check : [Start AlarmManager if device is rebooted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673746/start-alarmmanager-if-device-is-rebooted)