# Have an init script on Android that starts a browser full screen on a defined URL?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to build a system where I would hook up a small computer to a TV, and I need that computer to display a website in full screen as soon as it boots.

I know that I can do this with a linux distro, but what about an android ?

These sticks look pretty good: [http://www.amazon.com/CX-919-Android-Tronsmart-Ethernet-Adapter/dp/B00D05XSMY](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00D05XSMY)

Or do you know of any "usb stick" like that that's a computer ? I'm thinking either that or rapsberry pi, but the rasp is not really plug-and-play type of thing.

So my question is: Is Android flexible enough to have an init script that would fire up a browser full screen ? And if not, what would you recommend ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by init script you mean something that launches a browser at startup, than your only solution is to create a custom launcher, that does nothing but starts the browser full screen.

[Intent for browser launch.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3004515/android-sending-an-intent-to-browser-to-open-specific-url)

[Custom launcher.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107010/android-creating-custom-launcher) You have to set it manually, but after that it'll become the default launcher.

By the way, I would suggest Android sticky thing, as you said it's plug and play, and it has everything out of the box: storage, WiFi, Bluetooth, HDMI cable. If you buy a Raspberry even if software installation is easy, you'll have to add a lot of stuff before you can use it, almost doubles the price.

Comment: I'll mark that as a good solution, because it comforts me in the fact that Android might not be the right choice. Thanks !

Comment: It's not ideal, but it isn't as hard as it sounds if you have Android developer experience. But you're right, it's a lot easier to use Linux or Windows for this task.